# Salesforce - Bind variables only allowed in Apex code - MALFORMED_QUERY

Tags: sql, salesforce, soql

I need an equivalent SOQL query to this SQL query:

SQL query:

```
SELECT id, username, (SELECT username FROM users where id = u.manager_id) as manager_username
FROM users u
```

I have tried

```
SELECT Id, Username, (SELECT Username FROM User WHERE Id=usr.ManagerId) FROM User usr
```

What I keep getting is

```
[
    {
        "message": "\n(SELECT Username FROM User WHERE Id=usr.ManagerId) FROM User usr WHERE\n                                   
                    ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:57\nBind variables only allowed in Apex code",
        "errorCode": "MALFORMED_QUERY"
    }
]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOQL doesn't support field comparison. But in your case, it's not needed. The manager is the parent record, so its fields can be accessed via dot notation. Your query can just be:

```sql
SELECT Id, Username, Manager.Id, Manager.Username FROM User
```